# UITableView trigger when cell is reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having some issues with reusable cells in a `UITableView`. I have several types of cells, that I declare in the constructor.

My issue is that I have one particular type of cell that contains a `UITextView` and I have an issue when I scroll the table, the text within is lost. I need to save this text to the models that accompany the cells and then put the text back when the cell is used again.

How do I know that the cell is being moved away from? I have other types of cells, so I need a way to invoke some code to do the saving part on the scroll of the `UITableView`.

I hope that makes sense, if more is required, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to update your data model when *"the cell is being moved away from"* --- you want to update your data model when the text in the `UITextView` changes. You can do that by implementing `textViewDidChange(_:)` method of `UITextView` delegate.

Comment: You could also listen to `textViewDidEndEditing(_:)` and save the text to your model accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Just save the text once it is changed to the model, check if any text is present and use that in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

For more help you will have to show us your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can inherit `UITextViewDelegate` and in the `textViewDidEndEditing(_:)` check if the `text view` is edited, then you will be able to store the text in a variable or somewhere else and restore it whenever you are about to show that cell again.
If there is more than one `text view`, you might want to set an `accessibility identifier` for each kind, so you will find out which one did end editing.

Comment: using the accessible identifier for that seems to be fishy to me. why not do the proper OOP thing and use properties for a fixed number of views or identify the cell and get its index to query the data source for flexible amounts of views?

Comment: actually I think this better to inherit the UIView classes and define your own properties, although in my opinion, using properties like accessibility identifiers is very handy when you just want to check for `UITextField` name.

Comment: you are misusing the framework. And guess what: whenever you fight the framework, the framework will win.